# Dictionary with list as values and only want the first element like "code:%"

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I have a dictionary with data

```
dict = {1:["code: 1", "date: 01-01-2000", "date: 01-02-2000", "date: 01-03-2000", "spent: 20$"]}
```

I want to get this output:

```
{1:["code: 1",  "date: 01-01-2000", "spent: 20$"]}
```

So basically I only want the first element that have "date:" and the rest of elements

How can i obtain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    1: [
        "code: 1",
        "date: 01-01-2000",
        "date: 01-02-2000",
        "date: 01-03-2000",
        "spent: 20$",
    ]
}

out = {}
for k, v in dct.items():
    tmp = {}
    for i in reversed(v):
        tmp[i.split(":")[0]] = i
    out[k] = list(reversed(tmp.values()))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{1: ['code: 1', 'date: 01-01-2000', 'spent: 20$']}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = {1:["code: 1", "date: 01-01-2000", "date: 01-02-2000", "date: 01-03-2000", "spent: 20$"]}
a=[]
x=d[1][0:2]
y=d[1][-1]
a.append(x)
x.append(y)
output={1:x}
print(output)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?